# Best way of using Ruby module for configuration data

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am somewhat new to Ruby, especially the more advanced concepts like modules and mixins, so I might be using module totally out of context..

I am currently writing an internal test framework using Capybara and I am trying to figure out the best/easiest way of handling configuration data. I file a file called config.rb and within it I want to store configuration settings per environment. For example:

```
module QAConfiguration
   config data goes here
end

module DevConfiguration
   config data goes here
end
```

The simplest example of configuration data is usernames and password. QA and Dev of course use different users. I am thinking of two different ways of going about this but I want to make sure I am following at least a decent practice and not going into the weeds.

```
module QAConfiguration
  USERNAME = 'test'
  PASSWORD = 'test'
end
```

or..

```
module QAConfiguration

 def username
  'test'
 end
end
```

And so on. Which is the best way of approaching this?

Comment: There are several config-ish gems available, personally, I'd use one of those rather than re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

A module probably isn't the best way to implement this. Generally when testing (I use rspec) we use helper files that contain reusable code.

Object attributes like usernames and passwords are usually handled by Factories. A great gem for factories is [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).

Answer (score 0):

A common way to store configuration in ruby/rails is in a yaml file.  You could for example create a file called config/test_conf.yml with yaml format:

```
username: 'your_user'
password: 'somepass'
```

Then where you need the config data:

```
config = YAML.load(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/test_conf.yml"))
puts config['username']
```

And finally, you will usually only put a test_config.yml.example on git/svn and in your app setup readme note that they need to cp config/test_config.yml.example config/test_config.yml and edit the file.